# WordPress PHP Redirect - which hook to use?

Tags: php, functions

I have site where users sign up to a subscription. When the subscription has ended (I can query that using PHP), I want the user to be redirected to the "subscription-ended" page.

My current code looks like this, and it kind of works:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'sub_redirect' );

/**
   * This function checks whether the logged in user's trial has expired and redirects them to the correct page.
 */
function sub_redirect() {
    $user         = wp_get_current_user();
    $end_page     = '/subscription-ended';
    $current          = parse_url(home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

    if ( !is_admin() && ! is_wp_error( $user ) && $current['query'] == 'action=logout' ) {
        // make sure this is actually a WordPress user
        if ( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
              // check the subscription
              $subscription_ended = TRUE;
              if ($subscription_ended) {
                  if ($current['path'] !== $end_page) {
                      wp_safe_redirect( $end_page );
                      exit;
                  }
              }
         }
     }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that this also fires for when the user tries to logout. This means when I click on the link `https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout`, I also get redirected without ever getting logged out.

I am not sure that the "wp_loaded" hook is the correct one in my case, or should I just check for the "wp-login.php" url?